# Error trying to add +1 to value returned from list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of lists I am trying to use as a matrix.  In the last line of code when I add '+ 1' to the first argument in the min() function I get an error 'TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list'.  Can someone help me with the correct way to add one to the value I am calling from the list to compare?  Thanks!

```
   matrix = []
   for j in range(0,j+1):
       matrix.append([])
   j = len(t)
   for j in range(0,j+1):
       i = len(s)
       for i in range(0,i+1):
           matrix[j].append([i])
   matrix[j][i] = matrix[j-1][i-1]
   j = len(s)
   for j in range(1,j+1):
       i = len(t)
       for i in range(1,j+1):
           matrix[j][i]= min((matrix[j-1][i] +1), (matrix[j][i-1]))
```

Comment: Your code is not correct, it would throw an error as written (before the one you are reaching) so it's hard to say what's going on. what does `j` start as?

Comment: The code is really confusing: you reassign variables, then index variables are used as the number of iterations. It is easy to make a mistake and very hard to understand. Try to use index variables (*i*, *j*) only as indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should replace:

```
matrix[j].append([i])
```

with

```
matrix[j].append(i)
```

You want to append integers to list, one matrix row to be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
```

While you append lists to the list, which creates a row in the matrix as

```
[[0], [1], [2], ...]
```